# Using SMPS regulation output current below nominal Current

Tags: current, switch-mode-power-supply

I have one Switching power supply with Regulated current output similar to this (used for LED's):

[image: SMPS]

So my partner, is saing we could not use this SMPS as power supply for our microcontroler's because it could give us only constant current and do't working in less current of it's nominal current ( 300mA for example),

So dose it is correct?

I don't think so in this kind?

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specs you quote are vague.  To be clear, you say they are:

**300mA / DC9-16V**
  **AC85-265**

That *could* mean it's a constant-current supply with a compliance range of 9 to 16 V.  That could be appropriate, for example, for driving a particular string of LEDs.

On the other hand, it *could* mean that 300 mA is the maximum current this thing can put out.  In that case, it's saying that the output voltage is essentially unregulated, but will be from 9 to 16 V as long as other specs are met.  Those specs would include the line voltage and the current drawn from the output.

Given the wide AC input voltage range and the narrower DC output voltage range, I'm guessing this is a constant-current supply.  In other words, I think it's more likely the first case than the second.

You really need to go back to where you got this from and get more specs.  It should have been advertised as a "constant current" supply if the first case.

Comment: So could i use it's below nominal current?

Comment: The opposite -- it will attempt to raise its voltage until the circuit is drawing 300ma.

Comment: I would expect ~19 V comming out from it if unloaded.